# T is a map on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $T$ maps every line either to a line or a point and sends $(0,0,0)$ to $(0,0,0).$ Is it a linear map necessarily?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose I have a map on 3D space,such that it maps any line to a line or a point and maps origin to origin. Can I conclude that T is a linear map? If not, could you provide a counterexample and if yes, then could you provide a proof? I think it will help a lot to visualize the transformations geometrically.

Comment: Do you want to delete the first "linear"?

Comment: Suppose $f$ takes the origin to itself and every other vector to some, arbitrary, non-zero vector.

Comment: @lulu then it maps a line through the origin to two points, which is not a line or a point.  I would interpret the condition as saying that the image of a line is a point or a line, not a subset of a line.  But the OP should clarify this.

Comment: Robert israel is right i want to delete 1st linear.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  Ah, thank you.

Comment: When you say it maps a line to a line, do you mean that for a line $m$, the set $\{f(x) \mid x \in m\}$ is a line? Also, does "line" include lines not through the origin? And finally, are you assuming that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes the image set of any line is a line or a point.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider $T(x,y,z) = (x^3,0,0)$.

Comment: Does it map a line to a line,it does not.

Comment: Maybe $T(x,y,z)=(x+y,y+z,z+x)$ works

Comment: @KishalaySarkar: I wondered that too...but realized that it does. Any line not perpendicular to the $x$-axis maps to...the $x$-axis. Any line perpendicular to the $x$-axis maps to a single point.

Comment: @emonhossain Your map is actually linear